# Tomcat. Profiling with VisualVM and fixing possible bottlenecks

Tags: tomcat, profiling, visualvm

I need to find out if a server request has a bottlenecks or not.

I used the Sampler of the VisualVM for analysing.

I found two method-entries having long times:

> - org.apache.coyote.http11.InternalInputBuffer.fill()
> - org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.poll()

What can I do and is it possible at all to decrease the times of the both methods?

I also tried to switch to the NIO connector but it didn't help

[image]Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Is this for 1 single page request, or for a number of requests / period of time?

Comment: somewhere in the middle of this (http://grokbase.com/t/tomcat/users/08716hkj4a/tomcat-bottleneck-on-internalinputbuffer-parserequestline) there's a reference to "this is what happens," which might be relevant. if this is for a single request then the amount is significant. if this is a cumulative then I would think there's no reason to even consider optimizing, it seems to be mostly waiting on data/testing if there is data

Comment: @Joeblade Actually I just did one request. But I'm not sure if this request starts other subrequests. And thank you for the second comment. I'll take a look on this document